# Question regarding Sitemap value in a robots.txt file, and the lines of a txt sitemap

Tags: url, sitemap, robots.txt

I have two related questions.

To start, in a robots.txt file can you just put the following for sitemap:

Sitemap: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Or do you have to have:

Sitemap: http://www.example.com

or

Sitemap: https://www.example.com

My second question is the same thing but for the lines of a txt sitemap file?

Answer (score 1):

Either you've got

```
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Or

```
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

You can't do without TLS, and you're either www or non-www.

Your `robots.txt` should reflect what is accurate.

Comment: Thank you good sir

Comment: You're welcome, good sir